# Xaml, set default value in Slider

Tags: xaml, xamarin, slider

Can I set the default value in the slider?
Example I have a range slider between 10 and 100 and I would like to have defulat 50  when I open on the view whit slider

```
<Slider x:Name="TimeSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"    Margin="8,16,8,0"
                        Value="{Binding WaitingTime, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
private double _waitingTime = 0.1;
    public double WaitingTime
    {
        get => _waitingTime;
        set
        {
            _waitingTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

...

```
private void ShareCommandExecute()
        {
            var waitingTime = Convert.ToInt32(WaitingTime);
            if(waitingTime > 0)
            {
                var customPinModel = new CustomPinModel
                {
                    WaitingTime = waitingTime * 1000,
                    CheckinExtrasType = (int)_checkinExtrasType
                };

                if(_pinPosition.Latitude == default(double) && _pinPosition.Longitude == default(double))
                {
                    GPSManagerInstance.Checkin(customPinModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    GPSManagerInstance.Checkin(customPinModel, _pinPosition);
                }

                CloseShareLayoutCommandExecute();
            }
```

Comment: Does it not work? Post your viewmodel...

Comment: It seems ok....

Comment: It works, but I need that by default the value will be 50. When I do not set the value on the slider it will be default 50

Comment: In slider I can set  Minimum="0" Maximum="100". But can I set example  Default = 50  ?

Comment: try setting it inside a "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider's value is bound to your VM WaitingTime property.  If you want it to default to 50, then the default value of WaitingTime should be set to 50.

Comment: '     private double _waitingTime = 50;
        public double WaitingTime
        {
            get => _waitingTime;
            set
            {
                _waitingTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }'

Comment: something like that ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I was expecting the same, but its not working. In my code, property default value is 50, but as UI get loaded, property value changed back to 1. And slider also shows at 1. I am trying it on uwp.